# need a category url in product view page

Tags: magento2.3, category, product-view

I have a product bag in home->products->men->handbag category path .I want hangbag category url in product detail page

Comment: product view page url get in mini-cart ???

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code.

```
<?php
namespace VENDOR\EXTENSION\Block;
class Caturl extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
        protected $_registry;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        array $data = []
    )
    {        
        $this->_registry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function _prepareLayout()
    {
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

    public function getCurrentCategory()
    {        
        return $this->_registry->registry('current_category');
    }        
}
?>
```

And use it with below code in .phtml.

```
// print for current category
$currentCategory = $block->getCurrentCategory();
echo $currentCategory->getName() . '<br />';
echo $currentCategory->getUrl() . '<br />';
```

Happy Coding.

Comment: as per my category path ,echo $currentCategory->getUrl() gives the url of Men .but i need to get the handbag url

Comment: Please use this code to get full path.
https://ipfs-sec.stackexchange.cloudflare-ipfs.com/magento/A/question/130011.html